# Optional parameter is type checked and errors with type guard

Tags: typescript, axios

I am new to typescript, I apologize if my lingo for the language is off.

I want to make a generic function that optionally has an OAUTH token passed to it.

Here is my attempt:

```
import { AxiosStatic } from 'axios'

export function createAxiosInstance(
  axiosFactory: AxiosStatic,
  baseUrl: string,
  apiKey: string,
  clientId: string,
  clientSecret: string,
  authorization?: string | undefined
) {
  const headers = authorization
    ? {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-Api-Key': apiKey,
      Authorization: authorization
    }
    : {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-Api-Key': apiKey
    }
  return axiosFactory.create({
    baseURL: baseUrl,
    headers
  })
}
```

The `headers` object either has the `Authorization` property or it doesn't based on the parameter.

However, the `headers` object in the return statement within `axiosFactory.create` is throwing a typescript error:

> Type '{ Accept: string; 'Content-Type': string; 'X-Api-Key': string;
> Authorization: string; } | { Accept: string; 'Content-Type': string;
> 'X-Api-Key': string; Authorization?: undefined; }' is not assignable
> to type 'AxiosRequestHeaders | undefined'.   Type '{ Accept: string;
> 'Content-Type': string; 'X-Api-Key': string; Authorization?:
> undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'AxiosRequestHeaders'.
> Property 'Authorization' is incompatible with index signature.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number | boolean'.

Here is the `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "strictNullChecks": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "tmp"],
  "ts-node": {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs"
    }
  }
}
```

The `axios` library I'm using has the `AxiosRequestHeaders` defined and it appears `Authorization` can only be `string | number | boolean`. In my scenario, `Authorization` can be `undefined`. I thought the type check (checking the value of authorization) would have resolved this since I never consume authorization as `undefined` however this hasn't resolved the typescript error. Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: `axiosFactory` is defined by you? Please share its definitions

Comment: And your TS config. I can't reproduce this in [a playground with the default settings](https://tsplay.dev/wQbXAN).

Comment: Here is the axiosFactory, it is this interface, https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/4c89f25196525e90a6e75eda9cb31ae0a2e18acd/index.d.ts#L526

I plan on creating my own when creating an instance of axios. I haven't called this function yet, I am still defining it.

I also added the tsconfig.json file from the project, thanks!

Comment: @HelloWorld Could you please create a TS Playground or StackBlitz Project where you can reproduce the error? That will give us something more concrete to work with.

Comment: Right now this still isn't a [mre], unfortunately.  What can we do?

Comment: Apologies, I'm new to typescript and just don't know what pieces I'm missing. I did find a solution.

It looks like I had to type the headers variable and the type error went away.

const headers: AxiosRequestHeaders (this is imported from the axios library). My naive guess is that it was inferring the wrong type?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `AxiosRequestHeaders` type to the headers variable solved the type error.

```
import { AxiosRequestHeaders, AxiosStatic } from 'axios'

export function createAxiosInstance(
  axiosFactory: AxiosStatic,
  baseUrl: string,
  apiKey: string,
  clientId: string,
  clientSecret: string,
  authorization?: string | undefined
) {
  const headers: AxiosRequestHeaders = authorization
    ? {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-Api-Key': apiKey,
      Authorization: authorization
    }
    : {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-Api-Key': apiKey
    }
  return axiosFactory.create({
    baseURL: baseUrl,
    headers
  })
}
```

Without adding the type to headers, this is what was inferred:

[image]

Adding the type: `const headers: AxiosRequestHeaders = authorization` infers this:

[image]

As mentioned in some comments, there is likely more going on in my tsconfig that caused this, my original solution worked in a basic config.